# pygame - Circle cut off at 60+fps, fixed by display.flip

Tags: python, pygame

The following code draws a circle and moves it by 4px to left every step.

Problem is that at about **60 fps or more, the circle flickers and sometimes looks cut off** to me (approx. illustration below). The flickering is not like a screen flicker, more like **state switching between full circle and cut-off circle**. This problems doesnt occur at all upto 45 fps, couldnt be reproduced by screen capture or pausing the game, as if the problem is only visible to the naked eye.

Now, there could be two possibilities:

- *Screen is not updated over the required region.*

None of the update code depends on the fps, so the flicker should have been fps-independent. But, the problem disappears at 30/45 fps. But, surprisingly, it is also fixed if `display.flip` is used instead of update.

- *V-sync/monitor refresh problem*

Some other pygame flicker questions mentioned this problem. I thought software rendering doesnt have this problem, but not really sure. Also, why would `display.flip` fix this?

```
import pygame
w,h=800,200
fps=60
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([w, h])
color=pygame.Color("white")
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
radius=20
x,y=800,100
def get_bbox(x,y):
    left = x - radius
    top = y - radius
    width = radius * 2
    height = radius * 2
    return pygame.Rect((left, top), (width, height))

while True:
    old_x=x
    x-=4
    screen.fill(pygame.Color("black"),get_bbox(old_x,y))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (x, y), radius, 1)
    pygame.display.update([get_bbox(x,y),get_bbox(old_x,y)])
    clock.tick(fps)
```

[image: Cut-off circle]

Answer (score -1):

Checking out [Pygame's docs on display](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)..

It says on display.update:

> This function is like an optimized version of pygame.display.flip()
>   for software displays. **It allows only a portion of the screen to
>   updated,** instead of the entire area. If no argument is passed it
>   updates the entire Surface area like pygame.display.flip().

And for display.flip:

> This will update the contents of the **entire display.** If your display
>   mode is using the flags pygame.HWSURFACE and pygame.DOUBLEBUF, this
>   will wait for a vertical retrace and swap the surfaces. If you are
>   using a different type of display mode, it will simply update the
>   entire contents of the surface.
>
> When using an pygame.OPENGL display mode this will perform a gl buffer
>   swap

Which should answer your question as to why .flip draws the whole circle instead of .update.

Comment: I know all that about update and flip, and it certainly doesnt answer the question.